# Setting up Azure virtual machines with the same public virtual IP

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

What happens if two Azure VMs have the same PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS (but unique INTERNAL IP ADDRESS)? As in, what does that imply?

I'm specifically referring to provisioning machines from the classic portal (manage.windowsazure.com). Is it tantamount to being in the same "network security group" (in ARM parlance)?

I'm a newbie to virtualization and networking, and wanted to clarify this basic concept. In layman's terms, my objective is to have an arrangement where my DB VMs are not exposed to the public, but are part of the same lan. I.e. max security, least latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if two Azure VMs have the same PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS (but unique INTERNAL IP ADDRESS)? As in, what does that imply?

If you want to let two VMs share one public IP address, you need to put them into same cloud services. Then they will share the same public VIP and use different ports on public IP.

Here is the screenshot of my lab:

[image: ASM]

> Is it tantamount to being in the same "network security group" (in ARM parlance)?

ARM changes the network architecture, to shared one public VIP, we need to create a load balancer and assign the public VIP to the load balancer.

Here is a good [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/) which tells us the difference between ARM and ASM.